# How can I specify the same trait bounds on two generic types?

Tags: rust

My method needs both of its generic types to have the same trait bounds,
is there any way to write it without repetition?

```rust
fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> V 
    where
    U: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash, 
    V: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash, 
{
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alias trait bounds, but you can create a trait with some supertraits, and add a blanket implementation:

```rust
// You can only implement Foo on types that also implement Debug and Clone
trait Foo: Debug + Clone {}

// For any type that does implement Debug and Clone, implement Foo
impl<T> Foo for T where T: Debug + Clone {}
```

With those lines, you now have a new trait `Foo`, which is automatically implemented for any type that is also `Debug` and `Clone`. Then you can use `Foo` as your trait bound, and it will act as if you had written: `T: Debug + Clone`